# Почему нельзя освобождать одну и ту же область памяти дважды (double-free)

Tags: c, безопасность, память

Знаю, что будет undefined behaviour, но необходимо до завтра узнать в красках и подробностях, что же будет происходить при double-free, и, в частности, "все ужасы" такого понятия

Comment: "Неопределенное поведение позволяет компилятору делать все, что он захочет, даже сделать так, чтобы демоны вылетали из вашего носа"(c)

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы хотите узнать? Напишите программу с double free, запустите - она скорее всего вылетит, возможно с красивым сообщением об ошибке, возможно без. Этого недостаточно?

Answer (score 6):

Понимаете, на то оно и undefined, чтобы происходило все, что угодно. Вплоть до корректной работы. Так что всякие ужасы можно описать только "если в конкретной системе конкретная процедура работает таким вот конкретным образом, то теоретически возможно следующее...".

Например, менеджер памяти может запороть (и, скорее всего, запорет) необходимые для его нормальной работы структуры в памяти, так что дальнейшие выделения памяти могут приводить к неприятностям. Плохо написанный менеджер может, например, дважды выделить одну и ту же память :)

Вот в этой книжке - [*Безопасное программирование на C и C++*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1908-3.html) - описываются некоторые из возможных неприятностей, включая построенный на таком двойном освобождении взлом программы. Рекомендую найти ее и почитать.

А вообще-то, трудно детально и правильно ответить на вопрос "какую форму имеет бесформенность" или "какого конкретного цвета радуга" :)

Answer (score 3):

В общем виде менеджер кучи обслуживает два списка памяти - занятую и свободную. Когда менеджер кучи в языке Си выделяет память, то он перекидывает запрошенный кусок памяти из списка свободных в список занятых кусков. Также менеджер кучи сохраняет (обычно в куче) кое-какие структуры, необходимые для освобождения памяти. Соответственно, при освобождении памяти менеджер кучи пользуется этими структурами, чтобы перекинуть обратно освобождаемый кусок памяти из списка занятых кусков в список свободных кусков. Если два раза освободить одну и ту же память, то, как минимум, нарушится работа и целостность списков занятой и свободной памяти. Как максимум служебные структуры могут быть затерты и работа и целостность списков занятой и свободной памяти нарушится еще больше, если в данном случае есть понятие больше-меньше.